# Static routing algorithm for this host

Tags: networking

I have to make static routing table.
If i receive a packet for this machine, how will I know if the packet is for this machine.

What will be the calculation part and the entries in the routing table eg next hop

Any link or example would help

Answer (score 0):

According to IP protocol,the ip package have source and destination ip fields.So,Routing use these pair to decide which next hop for a package.

ip v4 head structure : [head](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header)